# TFS2018 TFVC incremental gated checkin builds building everything

Tags: tfs, msbuild

We have recently moved from TFS 2013 using XAML builds to TFS 2018 and TFVC builds using MSBuild v15.0. I created the new gated check in builds to mimic the behaviour of the old XAML builds.

We had previously created a 'Components' solution that held all of our projects and we set all of the Project Dependencies here. MSBuild was configured to build that one solution and what got built was the projects that had changed and any other projects that were dependent on those. This worked well and allowed us to easily identify the assemblies that needed deploying.

Since moving to TFS 2018 it seems that every project in the 'Components' solution is getting built, regardless of whether it, or a dependency, has changed.

I have not got Clean set on either the 'Get Sources' or the 'MSBuild' phase of the build.

How do I configure the build to only compile the changes???

[image: Triggers screenshot]

Comment: Are you limiting the 'Components' solution pipeline to running on a single agent? You will only get an incremental build on an agent that previously built the solution and kept the work folder.

Comment: We only have one agent, on prem. Where is the work folder? I have _tasks, _temp & _tool sub folders and the usual a, b & s folders in each iteration sub folder.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean a folder actually named `work`. I meant the `s` folder.

Comment: If you open your solution in Visual Studio and build and then build again, does Visual Studio report that all projects are up to date on the second build? If not then the incremental-ness of one or more projects has been broken. If all other projects depend on a 'broken' project, that would produce a situation where clean is turned off but everything builds.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanDodds for your time with my query. All projects we have will show Up-To-Date on a subsequent build in VS2019. I've spent this morning trying to understand why certain projects are being built and certain projects are not. I've tried various different log levels in MSBuild but I cannot determine what the trigger is. Any further thoughts???

Comment: (You probably know this already but to share for the next person:) With `-v:diag` (verbosity level diagnostic) MSBuild will try to report why a project is 'out of date' and is being built. To see more detail about what the pipeline is doing, add the [`System.Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug) variable with a value of `true` or check the 'Enable system diagnostics' checkbox.

Comment: I have enabled System.Debug and I'm still not seeing the information that I need. I can see a log entry of 'CoreCompile:' when an assembly builds and 'Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.' when an assembly is not built. However for some of the assemblies that have built I cannot see a reason as to why. None of it's dependants have changed, I've followed them down to the lowest level. There must be something I've missed!?

Comment: Based on your description, may I assume your pipeline is triggered by unexpected commits? Would you please share some screenshots with the pipeline builds history and let us know whether it is triggered by CI/Gated check-in? Kindly also check your pipeline trigger configuration following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/tfvc?view=azure-devops#ci-triggers).

Comment: The pipeline/build is triggered as expected but is building unexpected projects. The only triggers we have is Gated Check-in although in my testing to get log files out I have been triggering manual builds, using the source version of the changeset that was previously checked in. I would hope this should trigger the same components to be built. If not I would have to make a small change (to comments etc) to allow another checkin and gated build. I have attached a screenshot of my triggers to the original post.

Comment: I don't think the trigger is the issue. It is more likely something with the build content. Possibilities include that something is not kept across builds or is always restored/refreshed or has a timestamp in the future so it is always 'newer'.

Comment: But the million dollar question is, how do I track it down?